# GDB on Eclipse C++ Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am trying to use *gdb* on a C++ project using *Eclipse*

```
// T2.cpp

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int j = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

I have the toolchain *GNU Autotools Toolchain* and the current builder is *org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.autotools.core.toolchain.builder*

I use the build command: `E:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make -f makefileT2`

my *makefileT2* file runs just fine,
I create *Td2.o* with :

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra 
-fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB 
-DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include' 
-I'../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtWidgets' 
-I'../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtGui' 
-I'../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtCore' -I'.' 
-I'../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' 
-I'debug' -o debug/src/Td2.o src/T2.cpp
```

and link the *Td2.o* into *Td2.exe* with :

```
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug/Td2.exe debug/src/Td2.o 
-LE:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind 
-lshell32 -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored
```

Here is the debug configuration

[image: Debug Window 1 in Eclipse]

[image: Debug Window 2]

[image: Debug Window 3]

So when I put a breakpoint at int j = 0; and run the debug configuration this is what comes in my console output:

---

> - $1 = 0xff The target endianness is set automatically (currently    little endian) No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>     [New Thread 4188.0xf14] [Inferior 1 (process 4188) exited normally]
>     Quit (expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed)

---

And the breakpoint is ignored.

what am I doing wrong??

and what is the 'command file' *.gdbinit*??

Comment: The most part of information seems to be irrelevant to the problem. How do you set the breakpoint?